# Error installing Bazel on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bazel

I'm trying to install [Bazel](http://bazel.io/) on my EC2 Ubuntu machine. I download the .sh file with `wget` from [the latest Bazel release](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases) and then I run it with `sh ./bazel-0.2.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh`. I get the following error:

`./bazel-0.2.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh: 106: ./bazel-0.2.1-installer-linux-x86_64.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Looking at line 106 in the .sh file, I see the following line: `function usage() {`. Not sure why the `(` in that line would be an issue.

I've tried using other installers (`bazel-0.2.1-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh`, `bazel-0.2.1-jdk7-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh`, `bazel-0.2.1-jdk7-installer-linux-x86_64.sh`) and all of them have the same issue on the same line.

Comment: The syntaxes are `function usage { … }` and `usage() { … }`, isn't it?  Not the combo.  The Bash manual on [shell functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) indicates `function usage [()] { … }` (roughly); maybe `bash ./bazel-0.2.1-install-linux-x86_64.sh` would work?

Comment: Is this a bug in their latest release? https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases

Comment: I just checked their previous release and it also has `function usage() {`

Comment: Thanks, @JonathanLeffler, I just tried `bash` instead of `sh` and it worked! Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: The installer has a #!/bin/bash shebang that should select bash by default.

Comment: @DamienMartin-guillerez: If you run a script with `sh script`, the shebang line has no impact at all on how the program is run.  It is only if you use `./script` (or `script` or `/path/to/bin/script`) that the shebang line comes into play.  However, if the script starts `#!/bin/bash`, then it is a good idea to run it with `bash script` rather than `sh script` — because problems such as these can appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal syntaxes for functions are:

```
function usage { … }
usage() { … }
```

aren't they, not the combo?

However, the Bash manual on [shell functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Functions) indicates roughly:

```
 function usage [()] { … }
```

The exact notation in the manual:

`function`*`name`*`[()]`*`compound-command`*`[`*`redirections`*`]`

Maybe using `bash` instead of `sh` would work?

```
bash ./bazel-0.2.1-install-linux-x86_64.sh
```

<sup>*And comments indicate that this does indeed work.*</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The Bazel installer scripts have been updated to use syntax `usage() {` (w/o "function")